# The Measures hierarchy already appears in the Axis0 axis

Tags: ssas, mdx, mdx-query

I want to use the measures fields in both rows and columns in the `MDX` query and I have used the below query

```
SELECT{[Measures].[Average Rate]} ON COLUMNS, 
NONEMPTY(
  (
    TOPCOUNT(
      (
        Order(
          (
            ([Measures].[End of Day Rate])
          ), 
          [Measures].[Average Rate], 
          ASC
        )
      ), 
      201
    )
  ), 
  {[Measures].[End of Day Rate]}
) ON ROWS 
FROM 
  [Adventure Works] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, 
  FORMATTED_VALUE, 
  FORMAT_STRING
```

but when am using getting the below error.

> The Measures hierarchy already appears in the Axis0 axis.

Please share the steps to resolve the error.